# react-native-iap getProducts return empty array

Tags: react-native

I'am using [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) for in-app purchase. But the `getProducts` method return empty array. Below is what I did for it.

1. insert billing permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` like

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

2. upload this android app AAB to **alpha version** and didn't release it.
3. create product with id `productid1` and `productid2`. `productid1` is **active apk** and `productid2` is **inactive**.
4. make following code

```js
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

const itemSkus = Platform.select({
  ios: ['productid1', 'productid2'],
  android: ['productid1', 'productid2'],
});

...
componentDidMount() {
  RNIap.initConnection().then(conn => {
    // conn is true
    RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus)
      .then(res => {
        // res is []
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // no err
      });
  });
}
...
```

As like comment of [getProducts always returns null](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/124) by hyochan on 4 May 2018, should I wait for the products to update? or is there any problem on my code? or anything?

My environment is

- react-native: "0.60.5"
- react-native-iap: "^4.3.3"

Comment: when have you added the products?

Comment: @GauravRoy I added the products 2~3 hours ago.

Comment: wait till tommorow, and if still not there. then check again , coz its christmas time, and it may take time

Comment: @GauravRoy So, there is any way to check the product is registered? or just wait for it?

Comment: for me once it took 1 hour and for another it took 1 day

Comment: @GauravRoy I still receive the empty array(3 days passed). Do I have to release the app in Alpha test?

Comment: so there must be an error, https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb this article once

Answer (score -1):

For those facing this issue with iOS, make sure you finalise the agreements and tax, then make sure to copy and paste this `pod 'RNIap', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-iap'` into the pod file, then cd ios && pod install && cd ..(run terminal commands from the application directory).
I had this issue and it turns out I'd skipped these very important steps.